# Issue exporting with blender addon for three.js

Tags: javascript, python, three.js, blender

I'm working on a small project using the library three.js

We're using a plugin for Blender which allows us to export the model as a .json file, however the problem I am having is that when I export it and load it into the project, it's facing the wrong direction.

I've gone over the code and I'm sure it's not a coding error because
[image: Picture of 3D model in three.js]

I have the green line, (y), the red line (x) and a blue line (z), z can't be seen because we're facing directly down at the camera.

In Blender, the model looks as such:
[image: Model from Blender]

I am certain the error isn't from the coding side but an issue with the exporter add on which I found here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender

So I think I am more or less looking for a solution to fix the importer, it seems to be written in python, I am still searching around for a solution for this but not yet come across one, hoping someone else has had this issue.

Comment: It looks right to me unless I am missing something. Blender is Z up whereas  three js is Y up so I believe the exporter does this axis flip for you.

Comment: That wouldn't make sense though, z is the main axis for up, why would three decide to go about it differently?